# Chrome - "Unable to determine IP address from host name" from hosts file entry

Tags: google-chrome

I have a problem with chrome resolving an entry in my local hosts file (/etc/hosts). This is my host-file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost

127.0.0.1 mylocalpage.com
```

Unfortunately I got the following error from chrome when I try to access the page:

> **ERROR**
>
> **The requested URL could not be retrieved**
>
> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:
>   http://mylocalpage.com/
>
> **Unable to determine IP address from host name mylocalpage.com**
>
> The DNS server returned:
>
> Name Error: The domain name does not exist. This means that the system
>   was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if
>   the address is correct.

On all the other browsers like firefox, opera etc. It works like a charm. Is there a setting in chrome which I forgot?

I dont really know how to start here. Can someone give me an approach how to proceed here.

Comment: did you restart chrome after modification in /etc/hosts. Hope you are trying chrome from same server where you have modified /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems like a cache issue. Try clearing it at chrome://net-internals/#dns.